# How to get real time event of insert in SQL Server using node js without using a trigger

Tags: node.js, sql-server, real-time

I need event of insert in table and notify to my node js code in real time?

Is it possible to do this without creating a trigger on that table? If it is possible - then how?

I already tried service broker, queue and trigger but I need to do it without using a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a pub/sub system by using a redis server.

f.e

```
// subscriber.js
const subscriber = redis.createClient();
const channel = 'myChannel';

subscriber.on('message', (channel, message) => {
  console.log(`Received message: ${message} on channel: ${channel}`);
});

subscriber.subscribe(channel);
```

```
// Publisher.js
const publisher = redis.createClient();
const channel = 'myChannel';
publisher.publish(channel, 'A new row has been inserted into the table');
```

When a publisher publish a message on the `myChannel` channel, you can get those messages real time on subscribers.

Feel free to ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: thank you @Murat Colyaran. 
but we are using an SQL server not redis. 
it is possible  to get event of database table change in sql server ?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I don't know about sql events. But if do you have control on where you make the queries, you can do publishes there and that'd help you I believe.